# Problem in some Month of custom view - FullCalendar.io

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i have custom view like this:

```
 views: {
                dayGridMonthPersian:
                {
                    type: "dayGrid",
                    buttonText: 'ماه شمسی',
                    visibleRange: function () {
                        const currentDate = new Date();
                        const thisMonthArray = GetStartEndMonth(currentDate);
                        return { start: thisMonthArray[0], end: thisMonthArray[1] }
                    },
                },
```

**In some Month everyThing is ok:**
[image]

**but in some Month I have Month Style Problem :**
[image]

**how can I fix this??**

Comment: You should not need the visibleRange stuff just to create a month view. Just get rid of it and set `type:"dayGridMonth"` instead. (What seems to have happened is on some of the months the visible range your code calculates isn't an exact month and therefore it displays a standard grid instead of the specific month view).

Comment: @ADyson  I created custom type and use Jalali Calendar , in FullCalendar of type 'dayGridMonth',  Month start from 11th day instead of first!

Comment: Ok I see. fullCalendar doesn't know anything about that unfortunately, it only supports western calendar, so it cannot guarantee to work correctly with a different calendar system. If you want to request full support, go to https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features  and follow the instructions to create or contribute to a feature request.

Comment: Hi Rahman
I am working on fullcalendar too but I cannot find a way to start each month in jalali (1st of each month in jalali). I think you have found a solution to start each month correctly
can you help me with this and send me you calendar configs?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @AAV, i send it

Comment: Hi Rahman
what is ConvertPersianDateStringToGeorgianDate function in your code?
I know it is converting jalali string date to georgian but in the next line setHourse give me an error.

Comment: @mahdimomeni it's just Convert to GeorgianDate =>     const georgianDateString = moment.from(persianDateString, 'fa', 'YYYY/M/D').format('MM/DD/YYYY'); const endGeorgianDate = new Date(georgianDateString);
after set hours to end time of day

Comment: dayGridMonthPersian :{duration: { week: 4 }}

Answer (score 3):

may be useful for someOne.
for First and last day of Persian Month :

```
    function GetStartEndMonth(currentDate) {
    const splitDate = splitGeorgianDateToPersianDateArray(currentDate);
    const year = splitDate[0];
    const month = splitDate[1];
    const lastDayOfPersianMonth = GetLastDayOfPersianMonth(month, year);

    //Not Work in some Month !! => moment(currentPersianDate).clone().startOf('month').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    //Not Work at All in persian => moment(currentPersianDate).clone().endof('month').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    const startPersianMonth = year + "/" + month + "/" + 1;
    const endPersianMonth = year + "/" + month + "/" + lastDayOfPersianMonth;

    let startGeorgianDate = ConvertPersianDateStringToGeorgianDate(startPersianMonth);
    let endGeorgianDate = ConvertPersianDateStringToGeorgianDate(endPersianMonth);
    endGeorgianDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 59);
    const newMonthArray = [startGeorgianDate, endGeorgianDate];
    return newMonthArray;
}

    function GetLastDayOfPersianMonth(month, year) {
    //محاسبه کبیسه
    const leapMatch = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30];
    const number = year % 33;
    const isLeap = leapMatch.includes(number);

    if (month <= 6) {
        return 31;
    }
    if (month > 6 && month < 12) {
        return 30;
    }
    if (month == 12 && !isLeap) {
        return 29;
    }
    if (month == 12 && isLeap) {
        return 30;
    }
}

function splitGeorgianDateToPersianDateArray(georgianDate) {
    const persianStringDate = moment(georgianDate).locale('fa').format('YYYY/M/D');
    const splitDate = persianStringDate.split("/");
    const year = splitDate[0];
    const month = splitDate[1];
    const day = splitDate[2];
    return [year, month, day];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set

```
dayGridMonthPersian :{duration: { week: 4 }}
```